# Formatting HTML code in Visual Studio

Tags: formatting, ide, visual-studio-code

Can anyone tell me how I can format HTML inside of a .php file? If I could also format php code at the same time it would help a lot.

By format I mean automatically add the correct tab spacing between lines and elements.

All I can find is PHP extensions, extensions to format PHP or extensions to format HTML code in Visual Studio Code.

Comment: Code formatting is called linting.

Comment: It's a long shot, but see the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41330707/how-to-format-php-files-with-html-markup-in-visual-studio-code?noredirect=1&lq=1  about using the beautify extension.

Answer (score 0):

According to its documentation, this [VS Code Marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ecmel.vscode-html-css) extension supports HTML and CSS linting within `.php` files.

Comment: This doesn't add the 4 spaces when I enter a new line, and it doesn't format my document in any way. I wouldn't call this formatting