# How to format HTML in VSCODE

Tags: php, html, visual-studio-code, formatting

I have read many similar questions on SO, but none answer my problem.

I have a `.php` file with this content:

```
<?php something(); ?>

<div class="container">
                         <div class="row">
                             <div class="col">
Hello World!
</div>                             
            </div>
</div>
```

And I would like to reformat either the php or the html code, either globally or the selection.

I have tried all the `Format document` option, but it does not work.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd>, `Format document`

If I change the extension for `.html`, then it works.

Comment: hey you might need to install https://github.com/Dickurt/vscode-php-formatter/wiki - give it a try!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VSCode Format code command for PHP/HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32236030/vscode-format-code-command-for-php-html)

Comment: Yup, it looks like a duplicate, however, the linked question does not really give an answer to this one :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many extensions in the marketplace of VSCODE for formatting the code. Try one of them. I might even recommend Prettier ext. Try others as well you might one usefull

Comment: Well, It worked on html for me
Its your choice completely, the extension marketplace is full of options!